# Plugin not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-plugins

I am new in using CodeIgniter and I want to use a plugin or at least a working JQuery code. I have this plugin copied from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/4c5tt/). I embed the JQuery plugin by using these steps

- I copied the plugin code and save it as marquee.js and put it on my bootstrap/js/ directory.
- Call the plugin on my page like `<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>bootstrap/js/marquee.js"></script>`
- And lastly call it on my page by

  `$(document).ready( function() {` 
  `$('.slide').marquee({delay:3000});` 
  `});`

But the plug in isn't working, an error occured saying that `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'marquee'`. Any way I can solve this?

Comment: is your marquee.js file loaded, does it show js source when you click on script link from page's source view...?

Comment: is jQuery loaded before plugin, and only once in page? Check network tab in browser console to see if files all loading and paths are good

Comment: @Sudhir - Yes, the marquee.js is loaded and when I clicked it in page's source it shows the script. 
@charlietfl - Yes, I declare first the jQuery before the plugin. I checked the Network tab and it has this message: `No requests captured...`
Not sure why it doesn't work on CodeIgniter, but it works on a sample HTML script.

Answer (score -2):

Check jquery loaded properly

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Check marquee loaded properly

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>bootstrap/js/marquee.js"></script>
```

Check the class name of the div (`.slide`)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('.slide').marquee({delay:3000});
});
```